# WebGL Side-by-Side images causes image outline

Tags: javascript, html, textures, webgl

I am creating a map with WebGL.  I have the map tiles, so that the map is 2 tiles high and 5 tiles wide.  I have rendered the map, and I see a thin line around the tiles.  And what is even more confusing is that the outline color, which I suspected was created by resizing the image, is a completely different color from the image.  In this screenshot:

[image: map showing lines]

You can see that the color at the edge of each images is a dark blue, but the outlines are lighter colors, such as green and white in some areas.

[image: blown up image]

Here is part of my setup:

```
gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {antialias: true, alpha: true})
  || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {antialias: true, alpha: true});

...

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

What is causing these multi-colored lines to appear, and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the tiling of textures on an object.  Since the texture is resized, it uses bilinear filtering to make the images appear clear.  However, since the image repeats, it is blending with the other side of the image.  So the outline you are seeing is really just the other side of the texture since the texture repeats.  To fix this, add the following code in your "texture loaded" handler function (in my case it was `handleTextureLoaded()`):

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

That will produce the following result:

[image]